# How can I draw dots in Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, drawing

I haven't been able to find the help I'm looking for online.
I'm trying to place **dots** on my drawing - ideally just clicking the mouse / pressing the tablet pen where I want the dot to be.

The dot itself could be a very short stroke object, or a small circle with a fill - it doesn't matter - but should be visible. I tried using the **Paintbrush** tool, the **Pen** tool, and the **Pencil** too. I do not want to use the Ellipse tool and have to drag the tool each time.

[This](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eec0qXQ1QEw) is a good example of what I am trying to do. I also prefer placing the points myself as I draw them rather than drawing lines or shapes and filling them with points.

Comment: Did you have any problems with using the Paintbrush tool?

Comment: For some reason it didn't work earlier when I tried! Maybe my point size was too small for me to see it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I recommend using the 'Blob Brush Tool'(<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>) to get the **stippling** effect. It creates a circle each time you click or tap with your tablet pen. For small dots it might create irregular 2-point shapes.

[image]

Comment: Great solution, but you're not 100% correct: depending on the size of the dot, it will create a slightly irregular 2-point shape.

Comment: That's awesome!

Answer (score 3):

You can save a Symbol with varying size dots. Then use the Symbol Sprayer tool to your desired effect. However, Illustrator native tools will only get you so far.

I would suggest to try [Stipplism](https://astutegraphics.com/software/stipplism/) plug-in from Astute Graphics. That will give you the result I guess you are really looking for. (It isn't free, but they do offer a 14 day free trial)

Answer (score 2):

Another way to do it:

1 - Create a circle the size you need.

2 - Drag it to the Brushes panel and choose Scatter Brush.

3 - Increase its space to avoid muitiples dots close to each other.

[image]